# Form reluctant regex from generic regexes

Tags: java, regex, scala, apache-spark, optimization

I am working on a very generic case of regex in scala/java. I have a very large set of urls(~2 Billion) and I want to assign an id to each url based on the regexes(~70k) they match. Single url can map to more than 1 regex. The concern is with the set of regexes. They are very generic and hence are resulting into a greedy search. I have tried using [\w\W]*? in place of .* (see the sample below). But it is still extremely slow. The environment I am working with is Spark/scala. Any ideas how to optimize this? 
Here is a sample:

URL-sample:
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GC9PL97/ref=sspa_dk_detail_4?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B07GC9PL97&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=a54d13fc-b8a1-4ce8-b285-d77489a09cf6&pf_rd_r=Z6B30TKHBX693HZ53QWP&pd_rd_wg=Z3avy&pf_rd_s=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_t=40701&pd_rd_w=k7nGf&pf_rd_i=desktop-dp-sims&pd_rd_r=220cc48e-b142-11e8-ad5d-f9d1f1abea37](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GC9PL97)

Regex-sample:
.*amazon.*desktop-dp.* converted this to [\w\W]*?amazon[\w\W]*?desktop-dp[\w\W]*?

Comment: I doubt the regex is the problem. No matter how fast you make it, comparing 2 billion against 70k is too slow, even if a regex takes the same time as an addition.

Comment: I think that if you could merge the ~70K regexes into one giant finite-state-machine, you could scan every URL only once (instead of ~70K). However, there's a chance the finite-state-machine will not fit memory...

Comment: [\W\w]hy? Why should `[\W\w]` be any better than `.`???

Comment: Your regex

    `.*amazon.desktop-dp.`

and its replacement

    `[\w\W]?amazon[\w\W]?desktop-dp[\w\W]*`

are only very slightly related. Please fix all errors and enclose your code in backquotes to format it properly. Also add more regexes... if all of them are like the one you've shown, I'd use something else instead.

Comment: @maaartinus fixed the regex. * has a special meaning in stack overflow edit box as well.

Comment: @SKA Don't use backslashes to escape the special meaning. Use backquotes for code, so it looks like `.*amazon.*desktop-dp.*`. No escaping, just enclosed in backquotes.

Answer (score 0):

No that `[\w\W]` matches everything, while `.` matches everything but line break. So I don't think, you can gain anything by switching them.

You could use

```
.*?amazon.*?desktop-dp.*?
```

for reluctant search, but I don't think, it'd help. Instead of matching this regex, you can use a method like

```
boolean hasTwoSubstringsInOrder(String haystack, String needle1, String needle2) {
    int index1 = heystack.indexOf(needle1);
    if (index1 == -1) return false;
    int index2 = heystack.lastIndexOf(needle2);
    if (index2 == -1) return false;
    return index1 + needle1.length() <= index2;
```

}

which would be most probably faster, though the gain may not be sufficient. Given the huge number of URLs, you could use some preprocessing like extracting all relevant tokens, possibly using something like `string.split("[^-a-zA-Z0-9]")` (but using `Pattern.compile`).

Obviously, your pattern can only match, when the URL contains both `amazon` and `desktop-dp`. If your dataset wasn't that huge, I'd recommend something like a `Multimap<String, String> tokenMap` mapping the tokens to a set of URLs and using the smaller of `tokenMap.get("amazon")` and `tokenMap.get("desktop-dp")` for futher processing. I know nothing about spark, but I'd bet, it provides something like this.